# Get a specific element from JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I know this is a very simple and common question; I've already read some Q/A but I can't figure out how to solve my problem.

I have this short json from an AJAX call that execute a SPARQL query:

```
{
  "head": {
    "vars": [ "name" , "email" ]
  } ,
  "results": {
    "bindings": [
      {
        "name": { "type": "literal" , "value": "Name Surname" } ,
        "email": { "type": "literal" , "value": "name.surname@email.com" }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm searching name and email of a single user of the application, so 
the result should be always made up of a single element.

What I want to retrieve is the "name" of the user.
I tried something like:

```
response["name"].value
//or
response[0]["name"]
//or
response.name
```

but always wrong.

How can I get the name value? Thanks to everyone who will help.

Comment: try `response["results"]["bindings"][0]["name"]["value"]`

Comment: see more from here https://www.json.com/json-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the fiddle created here

http://jsfiddle.net/uqxp4j73/

The code for this is as under

```
var x='{ "head": { "vars": [ "name" , "email" ]   } ,  "results": {  "bindings": [       {         "name": { "type": "literal" , "value": "aadil keshwani" } ,         "email": { "type": "literal" , "value": "name.surname@email.com" }       }     ]   }}';
obj = JSON && JSON.parse(x) || $.parseJSON(x);
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj["results"]["bindings"][0]["name"]["value"]);
alert(obj["results"]["bindings"][0]["name"]["value"]);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Using brackets `["results"]` in our case is unnecessary. Much simpler use dot `.`, like in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
response.results.bindings[0].name.value
response.results.bindings[0].email.value
```

**Update**

[Example](http://jsbin.com/fitise/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, you always have to provide the full path to the property you like to reach. Assuming you have stored the parsed JSON in variable response, the following paths will get you corresponding value.

`response.results.bindings[0].name.value` for name
`response.results.bindings[0].email.value` for email

Recommend you to go through http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/ to get basic concepts of JSON.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll read that guide, it will definitely help me!